# Dezerialize XML where xml inside node can be represented as plain Text or as an object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

sirs, I have a case, when I

1. Make http request to rest resource
2. Get xml response
3. Understand what deserialized response is

I have generic method T Post(string uri, string body) that "knocking" to rest service and getting different responses on the same url and request format, for example

In one case I`m getting

```
<response>
    <status>OK</status>
    <statusCode>0</statusCode>
    <result>Sample response message here</result>
</response>
```

In another case I`m getting

```
 <response>
        <status>OK</status>
        <statusCode>0</statusCode>
        <result>
    <SampleEntityOne>Entity1 value</SampleEntityOne>
    <SampleEntityTwo>Entity2 value</SampleEntityTwo>
    ...
    <SampleEntityN>EntityN value</SampleEntityN>
        </result>
    </response>
```

So, how can I use something common when creating class that can be deserialized using `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`?

Thanks

Comment: What about checking if the `result` node has children, then deciding on what to do based on that. Like here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.haschildnodes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I calling method `T Post<T>(string uri, string body)` with type parameter.
For example, in my domain, I calling `CancelOrder Post<CancelOrder>(...)` where
CancelOrder is property of base response
`
public class ResponseBase<T>
{
public string Status {get;set;}
public int StatusCode {get;set;}
public T Result {get;set;}
}
`
but I can`t return 2  different results, I must return `T`

Comment: Your deserialize class for results need to have both a text property and all the SampleEntity properties.  The deserizialze method required all properties to be in the class, but doesn't care if there are extra properties in the class that isn't in the xml.